# regular expression pattern

Tags: java, regex

I would like to create a pattern, which matches all [ASCii decimal codes](http://www.asciichart.com/) from 58 to 64 (include 58 and 64)

```
String regExp=""; //ASCii decimal codes 58 - 64

//How to define above regular expression string "regExp"

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regExp);
```

How to define the regular expression string `regExp` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is with raw ASCII numeric values.

```
String regExp = "[\\x3A-\\x40]+";
```

Should match all occurrences.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use numeric values, try

```
String regexp = "[\\x3a-\\x40]";
```

You can't specify decimal values, unfortunately. See the [Pattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) doc for more info.

Comment: +1 for the extra information on decimal values. Good to know, thanks!

Comment: Hi, I used this regular expression, but pattern.matcher(";;;;;;").matches() returns false. Why?

Answer (score 1):

Just use a character class:

```
String regExp="[:;<=>?@]";
```

Comment: thanks but I prefer to use decimal code(58-64), how to define with ASCii decimal code?